# How to fix a missing bootmgr?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-10.04, formatting, opensuse, usb-storage

I want to install Ubuntu/OpenSuse through my USB pen drive. I have made it bootable by doing all the necessary procedures.

However, upon restarting the laptop to boot from the pen drive, I choose the USB DRIVE from which to boot, press F12, and it shows the error message

> "bootmgr is missing.Press CTRL+ALT+DEL".

Answer (score 0):

Format the USB drive in FAT32, and then use the steps to make it bootable.

Alternatively you could use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) - either way make sure the pendrive is formatted in FAT32.

Comment: Hey sathya ..... the file system is NTFS for the pen drive. How to make it into FAT 32 ?

Comment: I mean how can I change the file system of the pen drive ?

Comment: ok .... gottya !thnx btw ... let me try dat !

Comment: From Windows Explorer, right click your pen drive -> Format -> In filesystem select FAT32.